# Apache ignite back up copy distribution

Tags: java, ignite

I am in the middle of research on Vertx cluster providers. I have researched on Hazelcast, Infinispan, and Ignite. Out of them Hazelcast and Infinispan provide host aware partition back up distribution. There is no such thing available on Ignite defined on documentation. It says two nodes will have primary and back up copies of the same partition. It doesn't say if those two are available on two hosts. (If one host failed where two nodes containing primary and backup copies then the cluster will lose that data)

Is there a way to configure the Ignite cluster to distribute its data in a host aware manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the distribution using backup filters.

https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/configuring-caches/managing-data-distribution#backup-filter